# Which way is best for conditional rendering in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, frontend

When conditionally rendering, would it be better to show and remove via `display: none`

```
<View style={{display: props.shouldShow ? 'flex':'none'}}>
     ......
</View>
```

**OR**

would it be better to call a function like so:

```
const showComponent = (props) => {
    if (props.shouldShow)
    {
        return (<View> ... </View)

    }
    else
    {
        return
    }

}
...
...
const Thingy = (props) => {
    return(
        <View>
            showComponent(props)
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you mean better in performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you provided where you return the `<View></View>` or `null` is more idiomatic to react than toggling the style via `display`.

Comment: appreciate your answer! are there performance considerations when looking at these 2 approaches? Toggling display feels a little more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience and react projects i have seen, An efficient / trusted way to conditionally render a component is

```
const showComponent = props.shouldShow ? (<View>...</View>) : null

return(
   <div>
      {showComponent}
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a matter of display or no display I usually fall back to ternary expressions.

```
render(){
  let display = ( ...some expression )
  return(
    display ? <View>Hello</View > : null
  );
}
```

Returning null will not render anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Using Functional Component, The latest Approach then its much more easy as,

```
return (
<View style={Condition ? Styles.A : Styles.B}>

</View>

)
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({ A: { display:"none" }, B:{ display:"flex" } } )
```

Rest you have to look into functional component